# System Time Inaccurate on Virtual Box When Physical Computer Is Sleeping

Tags: virtualbox, redmine, turnkeylinux.org

I noticed today that the system time on my virtual box instance is inaccurate. Over the weekend, I put my computer to sleep.  I noticed that the created dates of records in my Redmine instance on virtual box are not the current date/time.  The sysdate on the virtual box must not update correctly after I wake up my computer.  Has anyone run into this issue before, and know how to fix it?

There don't seem to be any preferences that would fix this, and my searching seems to suggest this time sync should be happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being some sort of issue with initially setting the time. I can't seem to recreate the issue again, so considering it answered.